# send audio data from OPENSL ES callback to pipedoutputstream

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, opensl

I am currently working with OPENSL ES on the android device. I am trying to find a method of getting a pipedinputstream created in java from java into c++ and feed it the audio data every time a callback is called. I am also looking for example code if possible.

Thank you all, have a great one! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Hello, I am sorry I currently do not have any code to share that I am working with. I am following the audio echo example provided on github in the android ndk project sample listings.

Comment: It would help if you did sufficient research of your own to have a minimal example into which the missing pieces need to be added.  As it is, this is way too bread to answer.  It sounds like you have some of this - where's the Java code that creates and reads from the input stream, and where's the C++ code you have that's going to write into it?  Keep it minimal, of course - inputs can be hard-coded or generated where possible, for example.

Comment: That is understandable, I will do that, thank you I appreciate it! :) and The code I have is the same as the audio-echo example I'm just trying to find out how to write to a pipedoutputstream when the recorder callback is made.